# Openmp atomic and critical

Tags: c++, openmp, atomic, critical-section

I am new to openmp and am playing around with some stuff for a school project. I was trying to make my program run a little faster by using atomic instead of critical. I have this snippet of code at the end of one of my for loops.

```
  if(prod > final_prod)
  {
    #pragma omp atomic
    final_prod = prod;
  }
```

Although when I do this I get the error below (if I use critical the program compiles fine)

```
error: invalid form of ‘#pragma omp atomic’ before ‘;’ token
     final_prod = prod;
                      ^
```

From what I've learned so far you can use atomic instead of critical for usually something
that can be executed in a few machine instructions. Should this work? And what is the main difference between using atomic vs critical?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? It looks as if you're really after an atomic max operation, rather than just ensuring that there's no tearing in the assignment. (In your code, consider what happens if another thread updates final_prod after you have tested it but before the assignment...)

Comment: Note. Atomic read/write is totally a thing https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/608588

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Fruompatm.htm) you can only use atomic with certain statement forms:

[image]

Also, make sure the comparison is **inside the critsec**! So I assume you cannot have  what you want, but if you had

```
if(prod > final_prod) // unsynchronized read
{
  #pragma omp critical
  final_prod = prod;
}
```

it would still be data race

Comment: thank you for that, I actually didn't have the comparison inside the critsec

Comment: The IBM documentation is rather old. OpenMP 3.1 and later enable atomic assignment statements like `x = expr;` when the `write` clause is added.

Comment: @HristoIliev I half remembered such a thing which is why I linked to specific documentation :) Also, it is likely the source of the error message shown, hence the OP's question

Comment: What if there is a complicated operation like `vector.push(x)`? Is there any way to make this atomic in openMP?

Comment: @emab `atomic` in openmp is used in a stricter than just "atomicity" of any operation. So, short answer: no, `vector` is just not an atomic type. You can emulate this, as always, by using locking (mutex) or using a lock-free container implementation (that uses combination of atomic intrinsics to get you your atomicity guarantees). Whatever you do, don't "roll your own" lock-free container. Unless you have several years to devote studying and testing the subject :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the following forms of operators using #pragma omp atomic:

1. x++, x-- etc.
2. x += a;, x *=a etc.

Atomic instructions are usually faster, but have a very strict syntax.

Comment: OpenMP 3.1 added the `write` clause which enables assignment statements like `x = expr;`.